# How to pass a variable between php scripts using a database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have 1 HTML document (it is .php, but I'll refer to it as HTML doc) with 3 different fill-in-forms which each has their own PHP script for inserting the data into a database. Each form has its own script and its own table in the database.

I need an ID or username I can give the user on the first form's submission, and then store the ID/username variable and insert it into form 2 and in form 3. So what I need is to have a variable pass from one script to two other scripts.

I tried giving a ID/username in the first script, then in the second script I just collect it via SQL from the table. It doesn't seem to work.

Script 1: `$personID = 'a1';`

Script 2:
`$today = date("Y/m/d");
$personID = mysql_query("SELECT personID FROM reviewpi WHERE date >= '$today' ");`

Please help?

Comment: why not just a session? `session_start(); $_SESSION['personID"] = 'a1';`, then `session_start(); $personID = $_SESSION['personID'];`

Comment: **WARNING**: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications as it's being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: `"I need an ID or username I can give the user"` Give the user an ID? Like randomly generate an ID?  Be more clear.

Comment: Your sql retrieves every username where date is greater than $today.

Comment: Also, `$personID = mysql_query(...);` Not how it works. Read the docs on php.net to see how to properly do it; and switch to mysqli_* or PDO functions, as tadman said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who would like to know how I did it, here is what I did.

In the first scripts I added

`session_start(); 
$_SESSION['personID'] = 'a1b2c3';`

and in the 2nd and 3rd script I added

`session_start();
$personID = $_SESSION['personID'];`

then in my SQL insert statement on each script page (even script1)

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT into reviewdc ( personID ) VALUES ( '{$_SESSION['personID']}' )" );
```

My question was probably a stupid and answered question for some of you, but I couldn't find any research on how exactly to do it, and I tried most of the solutions given on other posts, none of them worked.

Thanks for those who helped.

Answer (score 0):

Your query tries to get the `ID`, based on today's date.

That is not a good approach at all, what if you had multiple persons that day?

Since you are just trying to carry the id over from page to page, a session would be the right tool.

**Set the session:**

```
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['personID'] = 'a1';
```

**Get the session:**

```
session_start(); 
$personID = $_SESSION['personID'];
```

If you find your self needing to get the data of that person.

Simply retrieve the ID and query your DB again.

```
SELECT * 
FROM reviewpi 
WHERE personID = ?
```

---

Please note:

- You need to stop using mysql, it's deprecated
- Use mysqli or PDO(recommended)
- Use prepared statement to avoid SQL injection attacks